# Extending homeomorphism of unit circle to unit disk

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

What is the best best way to prove that any homeomorphism of the unit circle onto itself can be extended to a homeomophism of the closure of the unit disk onto itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f:\left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}:\left|z\right|=1\right\} \rightarrow\left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}:\left|z\right|=1\right\} $ be
a homeomorphism.

Then $g:\left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}:\left|z\right|\leq1\right\} \rightarrow\left\{ z\in\mathbb{C}:\left|z\right|\leq1\right\} $
defined by $0\mapsto0$ and $z\mapsto\left|z\right|f\left(\frac{z}{\left|z\right|}\right)$
if $z\neq0$ is a homeomorphism of the closure of the unit disk unto itself, and extends $f$.  I don't know whether it deserves the qualification 'the best'. Maybe more something as 'most natural'.